# Fill out form with the results returned from search form Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

I have  created a search form in Symfony in order to find a serial number.
I have another form that once the data from the 1st form is return to fill out the 2nd form.

My Controller :

```
// ========================= Search =========================
    $formSearch = $this->createForm(SearchInstallationType::class);
    $getInstallationClientBySerialNumber = $savRepo->getInstallationClientBySerialNumber ($request->get('search_installation')['search_client_serial_number']);

    $serialNumber = $request->get('search_installation')['search_client_serial_number'];
```

The Render part :

```
return $this->render('att/att_client.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'AttController',
        'formSearch' => $formSearch->createView(),
        'formClientInfo' => $formClientInfo->createView(),
        'dataSerialNumber' => $serialNumber,
        'getInstallationClientBySerialNumber ' => $getInstallationClientBySerialNumber 
    ]);
```

My TWIG Page :

```
{% for installClientInfo in getInstallationClientBySerialNumber %}
                            <tr id="installClientInfo_{{ installClientInfo.idRma }}">
                                <td onclick="test('{{ dataSerialNumber }}');">{{ installClientInfo.serialNumber }}</td>
                                    {% for d in dataClientInfo %}
                                         <td>{{d.modele}} <br/>
                                            {{ d.marque }} <br/>
                                            {{ d.codeArticle }}
                                         </td>
                                    {% endfor %}
```

My JS :

```
    function test(dataSerialNumber){
    console.log(dataSerialNumber)
}
```

The serial number is returned fine in the console log but all the other parameters I add end up undefined.

If anyone could help, you would be a life saver.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you initialize `dataClientInfo ` ? you did not put into into your array in your `render` method

Comment: Yes I did sorry, I must not have copied it ... My bad